# A Priori Graphic Tool For Building Microservices

Tags: microservices, draw.io

I've spend a lot of time for searching a tool for draw A-Priori Diagrams of Microservices Architecture which can be used for create the first layer of OpenAPI Specification of the infrastructure. Which can be later extenden directly throw Json or Yaml and the original graphic output should be updated consequently.

So far I was unable to find out any tool that can help me to do so. 
I'm wondering if some who out there have in mind some tools for this othervise i will use like always draw.io

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these:

- https://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumldesigntool/
- https://sparxsystems.com/products/ea/compare-editions.html
- https://www.websequencediagrams.com
- https://www.gliffy.com/

I am not really sure if you can export the diagram to json and yaml. In some of them you can export to html and xml.
Gliffy is good if you want to have nice diagrams for AWS services and similar.